# How to give object different name using a for loop? Python

Tags: python, for-loop, turtle-graphics

I am trying to create Space Invaders using sprites as each of the aliens in the game. Instead of defining them all manually I decided to use a for-loop.
The problem is since all of the turtles have the same name so I can only interact with the newest one. Is there any way to fix this?
Just for clarification I am looking for ways to **define turtles in a for-loop while giving them different names.**

```
image_one = "invade_one.gif"
image_two = "invader_two.gif"

screen.register_shape("invade_one.gif")
screen.register_shape("invader_two.gif")

mod = 0
for x in range(0, 11):
    mod += 15
    invader_one = Turtle()
    invader_one.penup()
    invader_one.shape(image_one)
    invader_one.speed(0)
    invader_one.color("#eeeeee")
    invader_one.shapesize(5, 5, 12)
    invader_one.goto(mod, 0)

while True:
    invader_one.shape(image_one)
    screen.update()
    sleep(0.5)
    invader_one.shape(image_two)
    screen.update()
    sleep(0.5)

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: Looks like a job for `list`

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: @ClintonGraham, looks like you should put each `Turtle` into an array. Then in your `while` loop, you can loop through each turtle and update it.  The answer referenced in the duplicate flag does not seem relevant to your question IMO.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it's working now.